# Using kotlin-dce-js in a multiplatform js and jvm project

Tags: gradle, webpack, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to use `kotlin-dce-js` plugin in my **MPP** which contains two modules, one for js front-end and one for jvm back-end. I'm using the default `run` task:

```
jvmJar {
    dependsOn(jsBrowserWebpack)
    from(new File(jsBrowserWebpack.entry.name, jsBrowserWebpack.outputPath))
}
task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: [jvmJar]) {
    group = "application"
    main = "sample.SampleJvmKt"
    classpath(configurations.jvmRuntimeClasspath, jvmJar)
    args = []
}
```

As it's mentioned on the official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/javascript-dce.html), I have to use the `runDceKotlinJs` task to generate a smaller javascript bundle. But I have no idea how to use `runDceKotlinJs`'s output in my jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late...

You should be able to define / configure the output directory on the DCE options, like:

```
runDceKotlinJs.dceOptions.outputDirectory = "some-dir"
```

I hope this helps.